# FB api (js adk). Get all posts in group

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I try to get all the post in a specific group with the following code :

```
FB.api("{my-group-id}/feed",function(response){
   var posts = response.data // posts.lenghth == 24

}) ;
```

The length of posts array is not the same with the count of posts in the group 
How could I get all the posts not just a part of ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you get the latest 25 entries, you need to implement paging to get access to all of them:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging